# mongo shell: return only 1 element of nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have the following data on a mongodb:

```
{
    "name" : "bla",
    "log" : [
        {
            "A" : 1,
            "B" : 10
        },
        {
            "A" : 2,
            "B" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

I understand how to return all values of `A` from the mongoshell:

```
 db.test.find({},{'name':1,'log.A':1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52712539c99a2fc6f6088cd4"), "name" : "bla", "log" : [ { "A" : 1 }, { "A" : 2 } ] }
```

but how can I limit the output of `A` to only the first element? This is the output that I extect to have:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52712539c99a2fc6f6088cd4"), "name" : "bla", "log.A" : 1, "log.B":10}
```

I don't mind in having `log.A` or just `A`, or even having some `[ ]` in the output, as soon as it is always only one entry for `A` and for `B`

how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) array projection operator to do that:

```js
db.test.find({}, {name: 1, 'log.A':1, log: {$slice: 1}})
```

Outputs:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "bla", "log" : [  {  "A" : 1 } ] }
```